# Explain the result values of c program relevant with printf

Tags: c, printf

I was tried to print values of a float array with 7 elements. I assigned only 3 values and they are belong to float, double and integer.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){   
    float array [7];

    float f = 3.24;
    double d = 23.5;
    int i = 4;

    array[0] = f;
    array[1] = i;
    array[2] = d;

    int n = sizeof(array)/sizeof(float);
    printf("Number of Elements : %d \n\n\n",n);

    for(int j = 0; j < n ; j++){
        printf("%.2f ,",array[j]);
    }
    printf("\b ");

}
```

I got an output as follows :
Number of Elements : 7

3.24 ,4.00 ,23.50 ,-1.#R ,96627196995476105000000000000000.00 ,96629547147269436000000000000000.00 ,0.00

I want to clear is my code correct? And why last four values are different to each other. What are these values?

Comment: You are not assigning your array to any value. That is why before any assignment it is filler with **garbage** value.

Comment: Perhaps `float array [7] = {0};` would give you more predictable results and prevent **Undefined Behavior** that takes place when you **attempt to access an uninitialized element** within the array beginning at `array[3]`. If you initialize all elements of the array, you can iterate over the entire array without invoking undefined behavior, if you fail to initialize the array, you must limit your iteration to only the first three defined elements in your array.

Comment: note: this statement: `float f = 3.24; is assigning a `double` literal to a `float` variable.  To corrected produce a `float` literal, the last char of the literal must be a `f`  I.E. `float f = 3.24f;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last values are known as garbage values in C. 
If you do not initialize a variable explicitly in C, it's value could be anything before you explicitly assign something to it. This anything could be garbage; the language standard does not specify what it should be.

You can read this blog for How C compiler decides garbage values: http://blog.aditech.info/2008/02/how-c-compiler-decides-garbage-values.html.

Answer (score 2):

*First.*
Yes, your code is correct (add `return 0` command at the end of your `main()` function though). However, it needs to be more specific, which leads to your second question.

*Second.*
C is a language that allows a programmer to do lots of things, but it also requires the programmer to do lots of manual coding.

So, when you declare an array of 7 items, C compiler marks a region of memory to accommodate those items (in this case of the type of `float`). But it doesn't actually check what that region of memory contains until you explicitly assign the values. In your case the last four values (which you have not assigned yourself) are just garbage left in the region of memory marked for your array.

Once again, *compiler does **not** clear the memory for you when you declare the array*, it just marks the region of memory. It's your responsibility to assign default values to the array.

Your possible solution is to manually initialize all of the elements of your array to some default value (for example, a `0`), like this:

```
float array[7] = {0}
```

Comment: Thank you, David, just appended it to the answer!

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer and is there any reason to have values such as "-1.#R " and "0.00" ?. I am asking that because these two values are different from "96627196995476105000000000000000.00 " and "96629547147269436000000000000000.00"

Comment: Thank you! There is no reason whatsoever! It just happened so that on your machine the region of memory you've marked for your array and didn't overwrite with a default value contained some bits that the compiler interpreted as those numbers.

Comment: With modern C compilers, when the returned value from `main()` is 0 then not actual `return` statement is necessary.

Comment: to avoid implicit conversions, this line: `float array[7] = {0}` should be: `float array[7] = {0.0f}`

Comment: @SimpleBeat, the compiler did not interpret any of those uninitialized values.  Rather the values were treated as if they were valid values by the application as it ran.